# VB.NET: Label doesn't refresh

Tags: vb.net, timer, label, refresh

I think that these line of code should work properly, but the label never updates it's value... Any idea what am I missing?
Timer is Enabled from properties...

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim out As Integer = 13

    Dim s As String
    s = Format(out, "0#")

    Label1.Text = s
    Label1.Refresh()
    out -= 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the expected result?  You keep resetting `out` to 13 everytime so the same value will show every time the Timer goes off

Comment: And maybe you want to put `Dim out As Integer = 13` at class level.

Comment: oh, I'm so dumb...!!
After like 10 hours of continues coding it seems that I can't think clearly..
Thanks a lot!!
It works perfectly as a global variable..